# grab scroll in scrollview not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, scrollview

I'm trying to make a scrollview scroll by clicking and dragging on it. It does scroll but not nicely, it looks like it's rapidly alternating between scrolling the right way and scrolling in the opposite direction than it's supposed to. Anyway's here's what I've got so far
(this is in a custom mouse adapter):

```
point p;
JViewport viewport;
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{
        p.setLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());
    }
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
        Point ep = new Point();
        ep.setLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());
        double changex =  e.getX() - p.getX();
        double changey = e.getY() - p.getY();
        Point q = viewport.getViewPosition();
        q.setLocation(q.getX()-changex, q.getY()-changey);
        p.setLocation(ep);
        viewport().setViewPosition(q);
    }
```

Comment: Have you simply tried using something like [`JComponent#scrollRectToVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible(java.awt.Rectangle))?  You will simply want to calculate the offset from the top left of the viewable area to where you originally clicked and offset the final point by it (by subtracting it)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer So I think I did what your saying and it got rid of the strange scrolling behavior but now it won't scroll up or left. Here's what I have:


`public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
Point ep = new Point();

ep.setLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());

double changex =  e.getX() - p.getX();

double changey = e.getY() - p.getY();

Point q = new Point();

q.setLocation(viewport.getVisibleRect().getLocation());

q.setLocation(q.getX()-changex, q.getY()-changey);

p.setLocation(ep);

viewport.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(q,scrollpane.getSize()));
    }`

Comment: no idea, but you want to move with JComponent placed into JScrollPane, JViewport is only visible rectangle from JScrollPane, seems to be possible to convert mouse events from JViewport

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had a little play around with this idea.

Basically, when you click, I calculate the offset from where you clicked and the current viewports position.

When the mouse is dragged, I basically offset the drag position with the click offset, after making some boundary checks, I simply set the view ports position...

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestScrollPane101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScrollPane101();
    }

    public TestScrollPane101() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(new TestPane()));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/swhitehead/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/_cg_836___Tilting_Windmills___by_Serena_Clearwater.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                private Point offset;

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    Container parent = getParent();
                    if (parent instanceof JViewport) {
                        JViewport view = (JViewport) parent;
                        Dimension size = view.getViewRect().getSize();
                        Point mp = e.getPoint();
                        Point vp = new Point();
                        vp.x = mp.x - offset.x;
                        vp.y = mp.y - offset.y;

                        System.out.println("Guess = " + vp);

                        if (vp.x < 0) {
                            System.out.println("Under x");
                            vp.x = 0;
                        } else if (vp.x + size.width >= getWidth()) {
                            System.out.println("Over x - " + (vp.x + size.width) + " >= " + getWidth());
                            vp.x = getWidth() - size.width;
                        }

                        if (vp.y < 0) {
                            System.out.println("Under Y");
                            vp.y = 0;
                        } else if (vp.y + size.height >= getHeight()) {
                            System.out.println("Over Y");
                            vp.y = getHeight() - size.height;
                        }

                        System.out.println("Want = " + vp);

                        view.setViewPosition(vp);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    offset = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    Container parent = getParent();
                    if (parent instanceof JViewport) {
                        JViewport view = (JViewport) parent;
                        Point vp = view.getViewPosition();
                        Point mp = e.getPoint();

                        offset = new Point();
                        offset.x = mp.x - vp.x;
                        offset.y = mp.y - vp.y;
                    }
                }

            };

            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```